QField Sync Issue: Data Not Syncing Back to QGIS
I'm facing an issue with syncing data between QGIS and QField.
I initially synced my project from QGIS to QField without any issues.  I collected new data and made edits directly in QField.
When I tried to sync the changes back to QGIS, the data I added in QField disappeared.  The "Push Changes" option in QField is inactive, so I can't push my updates back to QGIS.
Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to ensure my changes from QField sync correctly to QGIS?
